# WPF Docking Manager with Databinding support

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, controls, docking

Does anyone know about a Docking Control like Visual Studio for WPF, where Databinding for the Panes is supported?
I tried the DockManager from Infragistics and from Actipro, but they lack this support.
For example, the Panes for the content need to be bound through Databinding, so removing the Entity on the other side of the binding would also remove it from the DocumentHost.

Any Idea? Or a lightweight workaround for any control? 
Full databinding support from every control is crucial for my project.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider [AvalonDock on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/AvalonDock/). If it doesn't have the functionality you are looking for you can add it yourself since you get full source code!

Answer (score 1):

I know this won't help the original poster but in case someone else comes across this with a similar question, there is a [blog post](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/andrew_smith/archive/2010/01/12/itemssource-for-xamdockmanager-elements.aspx) with a sample using an attached property to implement binding support in the Infragistics XamDockManager.